# Python django, importing database to html and getting a symantec error

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from product.models import Enhancements


def EnhancementsAll(request):
    enhancements = Enhancements.objects.all().order_by('name')
    context = {'enhancements': enhancements}
    return render_to_response('enhancementsall.html', context, context_inst$)
```

enhancementsall.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <div id='enhancementslist'>
      {% for enhancement in enhancements %}
        <p>{{enhancement}}</p>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The output I am trying to get is just a simple list of my products, instead I am receiving a huge block of repeated product:

```
Enhancements: Acetyl L-Carnitine>, Enhancements: Adrafinil>,Enhancements: Alpha-GPC 50%>,Enhancements: Noopept>, Enhancements: NSI-189>, Enhancements: Oxiracetam>, Enhancements: Phenibut>, Enhancements: Piracetam>, <Enhancements: Pramiracetam>] 
[<Enhancements: Acetyl L-Carnitine>, Enhancements: Adrafinil>, Enhancements: Alpha-GPC 50%>,Enhancements: Noopept>,Enhancements: NSI-189>, Enhancements: Oxiracetam>, Enhancements: Phenibut>, <nhancements: Piracetam>, Enhancements: Pramiracetam>] Enhancements: Acetyl L-Carnitine>, Enhancements: Adrafinil>, <Enhancements: Alpha-GPC 50%>, <Enhancements: Noopept>, <Enhancements: NSI-189>, <Enhancements: Oxiracetam>, <Enhancements: Phenibut>, <Enhancements: Piracetam>, <Enhancements: Pramiracetam>] 
[<Enhancements: Acetyl L-Carnitine>, <Enhancements: Adrafinil>, <Enhancements: Alpha-GPC 50%>, <Enhancements: Noopept>, <Enhancements: NSI-189>, <Enhancements: Oxiracetam>, <Enhancements: Phenibut>, <Enhancements: Piracetam>, <Enhancements: Pramiracetam>] 
[<Enhancements: Acetyl L-Carnitine>, <Enhancements: Adrafinil>, <Enhancements: Alpha-GPC 50%>, <Enhancements: Noopept>, <Enhancements: NSI-189>, <Enhancements: Oxiracetam>, <Enhancements: Phenibut>, <Enhancements: Piracetam>, <Enhancements: Pramiracetam>] 
[<Enhancements: Acetyl L-Carnitine>, <Enhancements: Adrafinil>, <Enhancements: Alpha-GPC 50%>, <Enhancements: Noopept>, <Enhancements: NSI-189>, <Enhancements: Oxiracetam>, <Enhancements: Phenibut>, <Enhancements: Piracetam>, <Enhancements: Pramiracetam>] 
[<Enhancements: Acetyl L-Carnitine>, <Enhancements: Adrafinil>, <Enhancements: Alpha-GPC 50%>, <Enhancements: Noopept>, <Enhancements: NSI-189>, <Enhancements: Oxiracetam>, <Enhancements: Phenibut>, <Enhancements: Piracetam>, <Enhancements: Pramiracetam>] 
[<Enhancements: Acetyl L-Carnitine>, <Enhancements: Adrafinil>, <Enhancements: Alpha-GPC 50%>, <Enhancements: Noopept>, <Enhancements: NSI-189>, <Enhancements: Oxiracetam>, <Enhancements: Phenibut>, <Enhancements: Piracetam>, <Enhancements: Pramiracetam>] 
[<Enhancements: Acetyl L-Carnitine>, <Enhancements: Adrafinil>, <Enhancements: Alpha-GPC 50%>, <Enhancements: Noopept>, <Enhancements: NSI-189>, <Enhancements: Oxiracetam>, <Enhancements: Phenibut>, <Enhancements: Piracetam>, <Enhancements: Pramiracetam>]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

PRODUCT_CONSISTENCY = (
        ('PL', 'Pills'),
        ('PW', 'Powder'),
        ('IJ', 'Injectable'),
)

class Enhancements(models.Model):
        name            = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        slug            = models.SlugField(unique=True)
        brand           = models.ForeignKey('Brand')
        form            = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=PRODUCT_CONSIS$
        description     = models.TextField(blank=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name
```

The code repeats like you see above several more times.
what is going on here? any help would be greatly apprectiated!

Comment: Just outputting a model instance in a template calls its `__unicode__` method. Presumably you have defined one with iterates through its contents. Maybe you should post the model, and show what you actually want the output to be.

Comment: Thank you, I posted the models.py

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct view? The code to have posted wouldn't produce this output.

Comment: Yes that is the only view I have wrote so far.